# How do i execute an external exe using a specific user

Tags: c#, windows, process, user-accounts

Im making an application which needs to monitor the filesystem using FileSystemWatcher, to detect how an installation affects the filesystem.

To get rid of noise i want to filter the events that are created by their creating user, and that code is working with the //BUILTIN //Administrator user, which is used by default when doing an installation. But still there are quite a bit of noise. Then i got the idea of creating a specific user that i can use for running the installation file, and filter on that specific user, and thereby getting rid of allmost all the noise.

this is my code for the process creation and start

```
private void executeInnoInstaller(string path, string fileName)
        {
            // Use ProcessStartInfo class
            ProcessStartInfo installerProces = new ProcessStartInfo();
            installerProces.CreateNoWindow = true;
            installerProces.UseShellExecute = false;
            installerProces.FileName = path + "\"" + fileName + "\"";
            installerProces.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

            installerProces.UserName = "test";
            System.Security.SecureString encPassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
            
            foreach (System.Char c in "test")
            {
                encPassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
            encPassword.MakeReadOnly();
            installerProces.Password = encPassword;

            try
            {
                // Start the process with the info we specified.
                // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
                using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(installerProces))
                {
                    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                    //int exitCode = exeProcess.ExitCode;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
```

this code exits with a access denied.

OS=Windows

Ive already tried to run the installer.exe from the OS filehandler with SHIFT - Rightclick using the specified user, and it works.
VisualStudio is run as administrator.
Ive tried to run the build project exe file as administrator, but it does not work.

Without the user credentials, the code works and uses the //BUILTIN //Administrator account

Does anybody have any idea ?

Thank you beforehand for your time and effort.

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `installerProces.FileName`?

Comment: Have you set the domain? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.password?view=net-5.0

Comment: the exact value of installerProces.FileName could be "C:\Sjabby\Installations håndtering\Innounp\HY-POLY free Installer.exe"

Comment: Ive just added these two lines             

`
installerProces.WorkingDirectory = path;`

It made no difference.

Im not connected to a domain.

Comment: Now ive have the .UserName = Environment.UserDomainName + "\test";
But now it returns a "Username or password is wrong". And i know it isnt. The username is test and the password is test

Comment: Ive also tried to make the .UserName into WinNT://WORKGROUP/DESKTOP-N4BFU0F/test but still the same problem. I know that the username is test and password is test, as i can execute the file using another user with those credentials from windows.

Comment: Did you try setting the domain?

Comment: Im on a computer that is not a part of Active Directory, but i tried to set the domain to WinNT://WORKGROUP/ while i tried to set the name to /DESKTOP-N4BFU0F/test or test or any combination of the parts of strings. Nothing worked. Also i tried to exchange the / with the \. Im quite new to C#, so :) It either gives me a Access Denied, UserName or Password is wrong, or Network Name not found

Answer (score 0):

This code works if i turn down the UAC securitylevel to the lowest.